# php.ini does not change values

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a virtual machine with [openSUSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenSUSE) Leap 42.3 and a [LAMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LAMP_%28software_bundle%29) stack.

Now I want to set up a [CMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system) called [TYPO3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TYPO3). The install tool tells me, that I should change following settings:

- Low PHP script execution time
- PHP max_input_vars is very low

I opened my */etc/php7/cli/php.ini* and changed the values. But after restarting the Apache web server, and executing [phpinfo();](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), nothing changes.

This is what *phpinfo()* tells me:

- Configuration File (php.ini) Path /etc/php7/apache2  Loaded
- Configuration File  /etc/php7/apache2/php.ini  Scan this directory for
- additional .ini files  /etc/php7/conf.d

Are my changes overridden? A system restart did not help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *php.ini* file in the */cli* directory is for the command line interface (CLI). Those changes will not affect if the PHP interpreter is "called by Apache" (or other web servers) in PHP's default configuration. You have to adjust the *apache2/php.ini* file. This is also what your `phpinfo()` states ;)

Restart PHP and/or Apache (depending on the system you are using) and it should be done.

Comment: there are no service called PHP to be restarted, he need to restart apache2 service, However you answer is almost right.

Comment: Thank you, the answer was there all the time, I did not examine the path carefully enough.

Comment: Ok, didn't see @hassan's comment. So I deleted my last one about apache restart.